# Openshift container with wrong openshift.io/scc

Tags: openshift

Having unexplained behavior in openshift 4.4.17 cluster: oauth-openshift Deployment (in openshift-authentication namespace) has replicas=2, the first pod is Running with:

```
openshift.io/scc: anyuid
```

the second pod goes in CrashLoopBackOff state, and scc assigned to it is the one below:

```
openshift.io/scc: nginx-ingress-scc (that is a customized scc for nginx purposes)
```

By documentation:

*By default, the pods inside openshift-authentication and openshift-authentication-operator namespace runs with anyuid SCC*.

I suppose something has been changed in the cluster but i cannot figure out where the mistake is.

Oauth-penshift Deployment is in its default configuration:

```
serviceAccountName: oauth-openshift
namespace: openshift-authentication

$ oc get scc anyuid -o yaml
users:
system:serviceaccount:default:oauth-openshift
system:serviceaccount:openshift-authentication:oauth-openshift
system:serviceaccount:openshift-authentication:default

$ oc get pod -n openshift-authentication
NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
oauth-openshift-59f498986d-lmxdv   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   158        13h
oauth-openshift-d4968bd74-ll7mn    1/1     Running            0          23d

$ oc logs oauth-openshift-59f498986d-lmxdv -n openshift-authentication
Copying system trust bundle
cp: cannot remove '/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem': Permission denied

$ oc get pod oauth-openshift-59f498986d-lmxdv -n openshift-authentication -o=yaml|grep   serviceAccount
serviceAccount: oauth-openshift
serviceAccountName: oauth-openshift

$ oc get pod oauth-openshift-59f498986d-lmxdv -n openshift-authentication -o=yaml|grep scc
openshift.io/scc: nginx-ingress-scc
```

Auth Operator:

```
$ oc get pod -n openshift-authentication-operator
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
authentication-operator-5498b9ddcb-rs9v8   1/1     Running   0          33d

$ oc get pod authentication-operator-5498b9ddcb-rs9v8 -n openshift-authentication-operator -o=yaml|grep scc
openshift.io/scc: anyuid

The managementState is set to Managed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should check if your SCC priority is customized or not. For example, `anyuid` scc priority is 10 and it's the highest by default.
But if other SCC(in this case, `nginx-ingress-scc`) is configured more than 10 priority, then the SCC is selected by the oauth pod unexpectedly. It may causes this issue.

Comment: yes, my custom scc was configured with 20 priority. thanks now is solved

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the customized scc (nginx-ingress-scc) had priority higher than 10, that is the anyuid's priority.
Now solved.